# Why is breeze "required" property validation rule not firing when validating new entity?

Tags: validation, boolean, breeze, client-side, required

I'm attempting to use the [Required] functionality for Breeze's Client-Side validation. I can do so but the only success i have had thus far is with strings. I'm attempting to do the same with a boolean but Breeze will not recognize any entity validation.

Here is my domain code snippet:

```
     [Table("Uwrl")]
public partial class Uwrl
{
    public Uwrl()
    {
    }

    [Key]
    public int customerNumber { get; set; }

    [Required]
    [StringLength(40)]
    public string customerName { get; set; }

     [Required]
    [StringLength(50)]
    public string customerStatus {get;set;}


  public int? taxId {get;set;}

     [Required]
  public bool coAdministration{get;set;}
```

Here is my controller code snippet to test for validation errors:

```
            var testEntity = UWRLService.createEntity(entityName, uwrl.customerData);
          if (!testEntity.entityAspect.validateEntity()) { alert("Didn't VALIDATE!"); }
```

Here is my view to ensure my particular property has z-validate in it:

```
                    <td style="text-align:right">
                    Co-Administration:<select ng-model="uwrl.coAdministration" data-z-required>
                        <option></option>
                        <option value="True">Yes</option>
                        <option value="False">No</option>
                    </select>
                </td>
```

Both customerName and customerStatus works. The customerStatus is even a select (drop-down)--exactly like the coAdministration property.  How does one validate booleans? Validating strings works perfectly for me...what's the difference?

Comment: Just a guess but the coAdministration property isn't nullable so breeze is initializing it with false right?  False is not null, so the required validation is not firing.  Check this by adding this line after the call to createEntity: `console.log(testEntity.coAdministration)`

Comment: So what you're saying is i needed to change this:
   [Required]
  public bool coAdministration{get;set;}

Into this:
   [Required]
  public bool? coAdministration{get;set;}

Comment: yeah- that's my guess- what did `console.log(testEntity.coAdministration)` return?

Comment: It returned false, lol. How do i prevent breeze from setting this value?

Comment: Again- guessing, but I think you could either assign null to the coAdministration property or make the property nullable so that it's not initialized with false

Comment: Yeah, if i initialize the property with "null" it works!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The boolean property is not nullable which means it's initial value will be "false".

"false" is not null or empty so the required validation rule is not firing.